# RavenDB - How do I query on both an object's properties and its children

Tags: c#, .net, nosql, ravendb

My problem regards selecting RavenDB documents based on both each document's properties and those of its children, from C#. Let's say we have the following documents:

```
objekts/1:
  {
  "Code": "1",
  "Children": [
    {
      "Role": "A",
      "Place": "Here"
    },
    {
      "Role": "B",
      "Place": "There"
    }
  ]
}

objekts/2:
{
  "Code": "1",
  "Children": [
    {
      "Role": "A",
      "Place": "There"
    },
    {
      "Role": "B",
      "Place": "Here"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I formulate a query in C# to select the object that has Code == "1" and at least one child with Role == "A" and Place == "There"? The query should resolve to `objekts/2`.

Also, how do I formulate a corresponding Raven index I can query against?

### Data Classes

```
public class Child
{
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
}

public class Objekt
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, we'll tackle the index, note that child keys are prefixed with `Children_` (required by Raven):

```
public class Objekt_ByCodeAndChildren : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Objekt>
{
    public Objekt_ByCodeAndChildren()
    {
        Map = objekts => from objekt in objekts
                         from child in objekt.Children
                             select new
                             {
                                 objekt.Code,
                                 Children_Role = child.Role,
                                 Children_Place = child.Place
                             };
    }
}
```

The query itself:

```
session.Query<Objekt, Objekt_ByCodeAndChildren>()
    .Where(o => o.Code == "1" &&
        o.Children.Any(c => c.Role == "A" && c.Place == "There"));
```

This query successfully finds the document with ID `objekts/2`, it's because of the child matching `o.Children.Any(c => c.Role == "A" && c.Place == "There")` that it's necessary to prefix the index child keys with `Children_` (e.g., `Children_Role`).

An alternative technique is to query on the index key type, and transform the result to the original type (e.g. `Objekt`):

```
// Index key representation of an Objekt
public class ObjektKey
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
}

// Query for ObjektKey instances, before finally transforming them to Objekt
session.Query<ObjektKey, Objekt_ByCodeAndChildren>()
            .Where(o => o.Code == "1" && o.Role == "A" && o.Place == "Here")
            .OfType<Objekt>()
```